# Why does the billiard multiprocessing module require the "if __name__=='__main__'" line?

Tags: python, program-entry-point, python-multiprocessing

If I have the following code:

```
def f():
    print 'ok!'
    import sys
    sys.exit()

if __name__=='__main__':
    import billiard
    billiard.forking_enable(0)
    p = billiard.Process( target=f)
    p.start()
    while p.is_alive():
        pass
```

The script behaves as expected, printing "ok!" and ending. But if I omit the `if __name__=='__main__':` line and de-indent the following lines, my machine (OS X) goes crazy, continually spawning tons of Python processes until I `killall Python`. Any idea what's going on here?

(To those marking this as a duplicate, note that while the other question asks the purpose of  `if __name__=='__main__'` generally, I'm specifically asking why failure to use it here causes dramatically unexpected behaviour)

Comment: Presumably, `billiard` is importing your code when run, which (if the guard is omitted) causes `billiard` to run again, importing your module, causing `billiard` to run again, importing...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You're disabling `fork` support with the line:

```
billiard.forking_enable(0)
```

That means that the library will need to spawn (instead of fork) your child process, and have it re-import the `__main__` module to run `f`, just like Windows does. Without the `if __name__ ...` guard, re-importing the `__main__` module in the children will also mean re-running your code that creates the `billiard.Process`, which creates an infinite loop.

If you leave `fork` enabled, the re-import in the child process isn't necessary, so everything works fine with or without the `if __name__ ...` guard.